# PHP POST single page form - hiding validation etc. initially

Tags: php, html, forms, validation, post

This is my first go at PHP and I've pieced together a form that all works on one page. The trouble is, it displays "Please enter your email address so we can contact you" when you first visit the page but I only want the errors/success message after the submit button is pressed.

Additionally, I would like all messages to be wrapped in a div when they are outputted.

I read a post that suggests using something like the following, but when I tried to implement, NO messages would appear on pressing submit:

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) 
{ 
    // Process Form
}
else
{
    // Show Form
}
```

Anyway, here's my full code:

```
<?php 
 $to = "me@gmail.com" ; 
 $from = $_REQUEST['Email'] ; 
 $name = $_REQUEST['Name'] ; 
 $headers = "From: $from"; 
 $subject = "Web Contact Data";
 $startmonth = $_REQUEST['StartMonth'];
 $startyear = $_REQUEST['StartYear'];
 $endmonth = $_REQUEST['EndMonth'];
 $endyear = $_REQUEST['EndYear'];
 $message = $_REQUEST['Message'];

 $fields = array(); 
 $fields{"Name"} = "Name"; 
 $fields{"Email"} = "Email"; 
 $fields{"Phone"} = "Phone"; 

 $selectedProjects  = 'None';
if(isset($_POST['projects']) && is_array($_POST['projects']) && count($_POST['projects']) > 0){
    $selectedProjects = implode(', ', $_POST['projects']);
}
 $selectedSkills  = 'None';
if(isset($_POST['skills']) && is_array($_POST['skills']) && count($_POST['skills']) > 0){
    $selectedSkills = implode(', ', $_POST['skills']);
}
$selectedNoRush  = 'None';
if(isset($_POST['norush']) && is_array($_POST['norush']) && count($_POST['norush']) > 0){
    $NoRush= implode(', ', $_POST['norush']);
}
$selectedWhenReady  = 'None';
if(isset($_POST['whenready']) && is_array($_POST['whenready']) && count($_POST['whenready']) > 0){
    $WhenReady= implode(', ', $_POST['whenready']);
}
$selectedBudget  = 'None';
if(isset($_POST['budget']) && is_array($_POST['budget']) && count($_POST['budget']) > 0){
    $selectedBudget= implode(', ', $_POST['budget']);
} 

$body = "We have received the following information:\n\n"; foreach($fields as $a => $b){$body .= sprintf("%20s: %s\n",$b,$_REQUEST[$a]);}
$body .= "\n" . 'Selected Projects: ' . $selectedProjects . "\n";
$body .= 'Selected Skills: ' . $selectedSkills . "\n\n";
$body .= 'Start Date: ' . $startmonth . " " . $startyear . " " . $NoRush . "\n";
$body .= 'End Date: ' . $endmonth . " " . $endyear . " " . $WhenReady . "\n";
$body .= 'Budget: ' . $selectedBudget . "\n\n";
$body .= 'Message:' . $message . "\n";



 $headers2 = "From: me@gmail.com"; 
 $subject2 = "Thank you for contacting us"; 
 $autoreply = "Thank you for contacting us. Somebody will get back to you as soon as possible, usually within 48 hours.";


 if($from == '') {print "Please enter your email address so we can contact you.";} 
 else { 
 if($name == '') {print "Please enter your name so we know who sent this.";} 
 else {
 if($message == '') {print "Please give a brief description so we can understand how best to help.";} 
 else {
 $send = mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers); 
 $send2 = mail($from, $subject2, $autoreply, $headers2); 
 if($send) 
 {print "Thank you. Your request has been successfully submitted.";} 
 else 
 {print "We encountered an error sending your mail, please check your details are correct or email us at hello@lyonempire.co.uk"; } 
}}}
 ?>
```

Thanks.

PS. If anyone wants to point out what is better practice for brackets and laying out the code, feel free. I know I could be doing it better, but not sure how.

MC

UPDATE - Here's the html:

```
<form method="post">

 <h3>Your Details</h3>

<div class="formrow">
    <input type="text" name="Name" maxlength="99" id="fullname" placeholder="Name" />
    <input type="email" name="Email" maxlength="99"placeholder="Email Address" />
    <input type="tel" name="Phone" maxlength="25" placeholder="Phone Number" />
</div>

<h3>Project Type</h3>

<div class="formrow">
    <fieldset>
        <input type="checkbox" id="type1" name="projects[]" value="Web">
       <label for="type1">Web</label>
        <input type="checkbox" id="type2" name="projects[]" value="Digital Media">
       <label for="type2">Digital Media</label>
        <input type="checkbox" id="type3" name="projects[]" value="Consultancy">
       <label for="type3">Consultancy</label> 
    </fieldset> 
</div>

<h3>A Brief Description</h3>

<div class="formrow">
    <textarea name="Message"></textarea>
</div>

<h3>What do you do?</h3>

<div class="formrow">
    <fieldset>
        <div class="skillrow">
            <input type="checkbox" id="skill1" name="skills[]" value="Website Design">
               <label for="skill1">Website Design</label>
            <input type="checkbox" id="skill2" name="skills[]" value="Social Networking">
               <label for="skill2">Social Networking</label>
            <input type="checkbox" id="skill3" name="skills[]" value="E-Commerce">
               <label for="skill3">E-Commerce</label>
        </div>

        <div class="skillrow">
            <input type="checkbox" id="skill4" name="skills[]" value="Content Management Systems">
               <label for="skill4">Content Management Systems</label>
            <input type="checkbox" id="skill5" name="skills[]" value="Video">
               <label for="skill5">Video</label>
            <input type="checkbox" id="skill6" name="skills[]" value="Images">
               <label for="skill6">Images</label>
        </div>

        <div class="skillrow">
            <input type="checkbox" id="skill7" name="skills[]" value="Social Media">
               <label for="skill7">Social Media</label>
            <input type="checkbox" id="skill8" name="skills[]" value="Strategy">
               <label for="skill8">Strategy</label>
            <input type="checkbox" id="skill9" name="skills[]" value="Best Practice">
               <label for="skill9">Best Practice</label>
        </div>

        <div class="skillrow">
            <input type="checkbox" id="skill10" name="skills[]" value="Not Sure">
               <label for="skill10">Not Sure</label> 
        </div>
    </fieldset>
</div>

<h3>Ideal Start Date</h3>

<div class="formrow">
    <label class="drops">
        <select name="StartMonth">
            <option value="">---</option>
            <option value="January">January</option>
            <option value="February">February</option>
            <option value="March">March</option>
            <option value="April">April</option>
            <option value="May">May</option>
            <option value="June">June</option>
            <option value="July">July</option>
            <option value="August">August</option>
            <option value="September">September</option>
            <option value="October">October</option>
            <option value="November">November</option>
            <option value="December">December</option>
        </select>
    </label>
    <label class="drops">
        <select name="StartYear">
            <option value="">---</option>
            <option value="2013">2013</option>
            <option value="2014">2014</option>
            <option value="2015">2015</option>
        </select>
    </label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="norush" name="norush[]" value="No Great Rush">
           <label for="norush">No Great Rush</label>
</div>

<h3>Ideal End Date</h3>

<div class="formrow">
    <label class="drops">
        <select name="EndMonth">
            <option value="">---</option>
            <option value="January">January</option>
            <option value="February">February</option>
            <option value="March">March</option>
            <option value="April">April</option>
            <option value="May">May</option>
            <option value="June">June</option>
            <option value="July">July</option>
            <option value="August">August</option>
            <option value="September">September</option>
            <option value="October">October</option>
            <option value="November">November</option>
            <option value="December">December</option>
        </select>
    </label>
    <label class="drops">
        <select name="EndYear">
            <option value="">---</option>
            <option value="2013">2013</option>
            <option value="2014">2014</option>
            <option value="2015">2015</option>
        </select>
    </label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="whenready1" name="whenready[]" value="When It's Ready">
           <label for="whenready1">When it's good and ready</label>
</div>

<h3>Estimated Budget</h3>

<div class="formrow">
<input type="radio" id="budget1" name="budget[]" value="Under 800">
   <label for="budget1">Under &#163;800</label>
<input type="radio" id="budget2" name="budget[]"value="800 to 1600">
   <label for="budget2">&#163;800 - &#163;1600</label>
<input type="radio" id="budget3" name="budget[]" value="Over 1600">
   <label for="budget3">Over &#163;1600</label> 
</div>

<h3>Good to Go?</h3>

<div class="goodtogo">
    <input type="submit" name="send" value="Submit Details Now!">
</div>
</form>
```

Comment: As for coding standards, here are some places to look http://pear.php.net/manual/en/standards.php, http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/styleguide.html and http://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Coding_Standards

Comment: Your code needs rewriting, the structure is horrible

Comment: @jayharris I did mention that in the question. What should it be like?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a Debugging request of larger chunks of non-isolated code that may (or may not) contain the code the problem asks about however there will be much reason and many additional issues an answer would require to touch next to deciphering the problem from this large amount of code.

Comment: for starters you need to wrap your validation in the `isset($_POST['submit'])` statement. secondly you never specified the name submit in your html instead its called send in your html.. 3rd to last line

Comment: @jayharris yeah I know about these parts - why does it need rewriting though?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDITED:**
As mentioned in the comment section, the first part of this is incorrect, I'm sorry for giving the wrong answer. I did not know that the action attribute is optional on html 5, should have done my research before posting. My apologies.

---

This is incorrect:

> Nothing is showing up because you did not specify which php file the form will be processed in.
>   Edit your your form tag to this (Replace the index.php with the your php file name):

```
<form action="index.php" method="post">
```

---

Also, the 'submit' part of

```
isset($_POST['submit'])
```

must match with the name of your submit button:

```
<input type="submit" name="send" value="Submit Details Now!">
```

should be:

```
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit Details Now!">
```

Comment: -1: The reason given is *wrong*. Please reference the HTML spec here. Different to what you assume, the action attribute is optional and has a default value. So if you answer, please take more care and provide reference.

Comment: Timber, thanks - like hakre has explained the first part is incorrect (you don't need the action in html5), however was first to shed some light on the submit/send issue which is where I was getting it wrong, so thanks for that.

Comment: @Mike: Please understand that asking a question this way is *extremely* unfitting for this website. As you can see a user who wants to help like Timber232 might get negative rep only because of you asking a question that can not be asked here - because technically his answer is wrong. If you are looking for Codereview, please choose other, better fitting venues like *Programmers* which are open to code-review questions: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/ - Albeit they probably will start to deny debugging requests on unisolated code-chunks as we now more efficiently do here on Stackoverflow

Comment: @hakre okay sorry - I was really asking about how to hide the validation/success comments and wrap them in a div, but added the code-review stuff because I got a couple of other users on this site telling me it should be better, but without info on how to do it..

Comment: @Mike: Instead provide an isolated example then give reference why you think what you want to do is possible. That's important. Users reading your question must be able to execute the code and reproduce your issue. Your work is to think about isolating the problem first. (Which normally also makes you writing better code if not even solving the problem(s) already).